# Css files not registering in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

- I was attempting to import a css file into my reactjs code. The code didn't seem to register it and the autofill didn't show any css files.

I tried moving the css file to a different folder and restarting my computer. I was expecting it to register the css but it didn't.

[image: Image:]